# APFS-formatted macOS Monterey SSD got corrupted after attempting to Clone using Target Mode

Tags: macos, partition, ssd, apfs, data-recovery

My iMac Late 2015 27" equipped with an original Apple 1TB SSD and an installed macOS Monterey showed an odd behavior by occasional Kernel Panics which I couldn't explain on the first sight and analysis. Hence I decided to create a clone-backup using CCC by putting the iMac into target mode. Something went wrong for the very first time using this method: CCC started for a fraction of second and resulting in a "Successfully cloned" message. After this the APFS-SSD was corrupted (I don't want to blame CCC here, my "procedure"-chain failed).

I have read a lot of similar issues here but since I'm more a hardware-guy, it's hard for me to get the full understanding of what is advised and understand the underlying mechanics. So I hope that one of the Guru's here might get a clue out of what I will provide on data.

Trying to use Disk Utility always ends up in different errors, depending on which partition I'm trying to fix (the second drive is a rotating HDD which plays no role here, since there's no data on it):

[image]

[image: Tons of errors appear]

[image]

[image]

Thanks to all the questioners with similar problems, I was able to enter the appropriate terminal commands to post the results here and hopefully get help by recovering my SSD.

Output of `diskutil list /dev/disk0`:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         1.0 TB     disk0s2
```

Output of `gpt -v -r show /dev/disk0`:

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1953800440      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1954210080           7         
  1954210087          32         Sec GPT table
  1954210119           1         Sec GPT header
```

Output of `fdisk /dev/disk0`:

```
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 - 1954210119] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Output of `diskutil apfs list`:

```
|
+-- Container ERROR -69808
|   ======================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk2
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      ERROR -69620
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   ERROR -69620
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       ERROR -69620
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk0s2 C52C5D54-EC72-4E8E-9CA0-6C8E4EBC0165
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
|   |   Size:                       1000345825280 B (1.0 TB)
|   |
|   +-> No Volumes
```

(I dropped the listed disk4 here, since this is the OS I was booting from externally via USB-attached SSD)

Output of `diskutil info /dev/disk0`:

```
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD SM1024G

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 1.0 TB (1000555581440 Bytes) (exactly 1954210120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No
   Device Location:           "SSD"
```

Output of `fsck_apfs -y  /dev/disk0s2`:

```
error: object (oid 0x148ef1): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xf should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 169 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x148f38): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xf should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 170 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x14919b): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xb should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 171 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x149210): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xb should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 172 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x405): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 173 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1671c1): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 174 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x167589): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 175 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1664ba): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xe should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 177 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x150edc): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xb should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 178 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0xe8fa0): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xe should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 179 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x14934a): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xb should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 180 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x14a108): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xb should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 181 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x14a401): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xb should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 182 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x10821c): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xe should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 183 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x14a674): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xb should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 184 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x403): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 185 fsck_obj_phys failed
warning: checkpoint 186 obj->o_type is invalid: (0x80000012)
warning: checkpoint 187 obj->o_type is invalid: (0x4000000b)
warning: checkpoint 188 obj->o_type is invalid: (0x80000005)
error: object (oid 0x1675a3): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 189 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0xffffffffffffffff): o_cksum (0xfffffffffffffff9) is invalid for object
error: object (oid 0xffffffffffffffff): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xc000000 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 190 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x167596): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 191 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1675a3): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 192 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x16759b): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 193 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x16759b): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 194 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1675a3): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 195 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1675ac): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 196 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x16759b): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 197 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1675ac): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 198 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x16759b): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 199 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1675ac): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 200 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1671c1): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 201 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x1675ac): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x9 should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 202 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x20000010000008a): o_cksum (0x200000100000001) is invalid for object
error: object (oid 0x20000010000008a): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x444d6b5f should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 225 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: object (oid 0x14a3c3): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0xf should be 0x0
warning: checkpoint 227 fsck_obj_phys failed
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_oid (0x149507)
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_type (0x4000000b, expected 0xd)
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_type (0x4000000b, expected 0xd)
warning: checkpoint 232 (xid 345093) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_oid (0x149507)
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_type (0x4000000b, expected 0xd)
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_type (0x4000000b, expected 0xd)
warning: checkpoint 210 (xid 345082) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x1493f7) om: invalid o_oid (0x1499fc)
error: (oid 0x1493f7) om: invalid o_xid (0x543fb)
error: (oid 0x1493f7) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 208 (xid 345081) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_oid (0x149507)
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_type (0x4000000b, expected 0xd)
error: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_type (0x4000000b, expected 0xd)
warning: checkpoint 206 (xid 345080) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0xcc) cpm: found zeroed-out block
warning: checkpoint 204 (xid 345079) checkpoint map is invalid
error: (oid 0x14edec) om: invalid o_oid (0x1505b1)
error: (oid 0x14edec) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f0)
error: (oid 0x14edec) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x14edec) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 168 (xid 345061) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14e8be) om: invalid o_oid (0x71fc8)
error: (oid 0x14e8be) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f0)
error: (oid 0x14e8be) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x14e8be) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 166 (xid 345060) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14e16c) om: invalid o_oid (0x7302d)
error: (oid 0x14e16c) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f0)
error: (oid 0x14e16c) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x14e16c) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 164 (xid 345059) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14d4b8) om: invalid o_oid (0x14d487)
error: (oid 0x14d4b8) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f0)
error: (oid 0x14d4b8) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 162 (xid 345058) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149225) om: invalid o_oid (0x16658d)
error: (oid 0x149225) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f9)
error: (oid 0x149225) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x149225) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 160 (xid 345057) failed consistency check
warning: (oid 0x148f2c) om: invalid o_cksum (0x1)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 158 (xid 345056) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14af52) om: invalid o_oid (0x149f78)
error: (oid 0x14af52) om: invalid o_xid (0x543ea)
error: (oid 0x14af52) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 156 (xid 345055) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149077) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 154 (xid 345054) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14a892) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 152 (xid 345053) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x1490e6) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 150 (xid 345052) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149c5e) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 148 (xid 345051) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149200) om: invalid o_oid (0x2e31f)
error: (oid 0x149200) om: invalid o_xid (0x543e4)
error: (oid 0x149200) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x149200) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 146 (xid 345050) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x1495a9) om: invalid o_oid (0xb2c4a)
error: (oid 0x1495a9) om: invalid o_xid (0x543e3)
error: (oid 0x1495a9) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x1495a9) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 144 (xid 345049) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149734) om: invalid o_oid (0xe8fba)
error: (oid 0x149734) om: invalid o_xid (0x543e2)
error: (oid 0x149734) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x149734) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 141 (xid 345048) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149561) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 138 (xid 345047) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149622) om: invalid o_oid (0x1090b5)
error: (oid 0x149622) om: invalid o_xid (0x543e2)
error: (oid 0x149622) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x149622) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 135 (xid 345046) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14a717) om: invalid o_oid (0x14a64f)
error: (oid 0x14a717) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f7)
error: (oid 0x14a717) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 132 (xid 345045) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x402) apfs: found zeroed-out block
warning: checkpoint 129 (xid 345044) failed consistency check
warning: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
warning: checkpoint 126 (xid 345043) failed consistency check
warning: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
warning: checkpoint 123 (xid 345042) failed consistency check
warning: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
warning: checkpoint 120 (xid 345041) failed consistency check
warning: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
warning: checkpoint 117 (xid 345040) failed consistency check
warning: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
warning: checkpoint 114 (xid 345039) failed consistency check
warning: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
warning: checkpoint 111 (xid 345038) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14e5ba) om: invalid o_oid (0x71fd5)
error: (oid 0x14e5ba) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f0)
error: (oid 0x14e5ba) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x14e5ba) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 108 (xid 345037) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x149151) om: invalid o_oid (0x405)
error: (oid 0x149151) om: invalid o_xid (0x543ea)
error: (oid 0x149151) om: invalid o_type (0x80000002, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x149151) om: invalid o_type (0x80000002, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 105 (xid 345036) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x16ed70) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 102 (xid 345035) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x1729f9) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d5)
error: (oid 0x1729f9) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 99 (xid 345034) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x174a43) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d4)
error: (oid 0x174a43) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 96 (xid 345033) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x173df1) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d3)
error: (oid 0x173df1) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 93 (xid 345032) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x172d5b) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d2)
error: (oid 0x172d5b) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 90 (xid 345031) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x172296) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 87 (xid 345030) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x171c25) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d0)
error: (oid 0x171c25) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 84 (xid 345029) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x16fe6c) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cf)
error: (oid 0x16fe6c) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 81 (xid 345028) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x169864) om: invalid o_xid (0x543ce)
error: (oid 0x169864) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 78 (xid 345027) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x16f555) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cd)
error: (oid 0x16f555) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 75 (xid 345026) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x153f73) om: invalid o_oid (0x153f63)
error: (oid 0x153f73) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f3)
error: (oid 0x153f73) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 71 (xid 345025) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x16e8d6) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 68 (xid 345024) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x176467) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 64 (xid 345023) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x175e97) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cd)
error: (oid 0x175e97) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 60 (xid 345022) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x175832) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cc)
error: (oid 0x175832) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 56 (xid 345021) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x174ff4) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 52 (xid 345020) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x174812) om: invalid o_xid (0x543c9)
error: (oid 0x174812) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 48 (xid 345019) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x173d88) om: invalid o_xid (0x543c8)
error: (oid 0x173d88) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 44 (xid 345018) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x14e471) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d0)
error: (oid 0x14e471) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 40 (xid 345017) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x17303d) om: invalid o_xid (0x543c8)
error: (oid 0x17303d) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 36 (xid 345016) failed consistency check
Too many warnings of this type generated; suppressing subsequent ones.
error: (oid 0x170182) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cf)
error: (oid 0x170182) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x16fbbb) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cf)
error: (oid 0x16fbbb) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x149610) om: invalid o_oid (0x1495e1)
error: (oid 0x149610) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f0)
error: (oid 0x149610) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: (oid 0x149269) om: invalid o_cksum (0x1)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x16850d) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cb)
error: (oid 0x16850d) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x16781c) om: invalid o_xid (0x543bc)
error: (oid 0x16781c) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x16718e) om: invalid o_xid (0x543cd)
error: (oid 0x16718e) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x15dfa7) om: invalid o_xid (0x543c5)
error: (oid 0x15dfa7) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x152b7c) om: invalid o_xid (0x543ba)
error: (oid 0x152b7c) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x1525fb) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d3)
error: (oid 0x1525fb) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x149acf) om: invalid o_xid (0x543c4)
error: (oid 0x149acf) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x1498f0) om: invalid o_xid (0x543d0)
error: (oid 0x1498f0) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x14962d) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x14951f) om: invalid o_oid (0x149be9)
error: (oid 0x14951f) om: invalid o_xid (0x543fb)
error: (oid 0x14951f) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x1491c0) om: invalid o_xid (0x543c7)
error: (oid 0x1491c0) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x1490c0) om: invalid o_oid (0x166786)
error: (oid 0x1490c0) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f9)
error: (oid 0x1490c0) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x1490c0) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: (oid 0x148f4f) om: invalid o_cksum (0x1)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: (oid 0x148f4f) om: invalid o_cksum (0x1)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: (oid 0x148f4f) om: invalid o_cksum (0x1)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f8)
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f8)
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f8)
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f8)
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f8)
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_xid (0x543f8)
error: (oid 0x148fe6) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x14904e) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x14904e) om: found zeroed-out block
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x14aa42) om: invalid o_oid (0x1671bc)
error: (oid 0x14aa42) om: invalid o_xid (0x543df)
error: (oid 0x14aa42) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: (oid 0x14aa42) om: invalid o_type (0x3, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
error: (oid 0x14a179) om: invalid o_xid (0x543ca)
error: (oid 0x14a179) om: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x4000000b)
error: verification/reading of the omap object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: (oid 0x4be) apfs: invalid o_cksum (0xffffffffffffffff)
error: no valid checkpoint
   Most recent checkpoint is invalid.
** The container /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely.
```

Since I was able to identify the root-cause for the unstable behaviour of the Mac, I finally hope that someone can tell me the right values that might recover my valuable data.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you saying that the source became corrupted as part of the clone?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all who took the time to read all along. Finally I was able to almost completely recover the SSD with 930GB of data using "Disk Drill" from cleverfiles. Only 15 files were damaged so hard, that they cannot be read, which to me is a real great result!

This issue has been resolved successfully :-)

Comment: Congrats! It would be nice if you could update your answer with some details such as the type (free/pro) and version of Disk Drill you used and how you used it.